# How to pass data from $http.get to request body in angular

Tags: angularjs, express

I am using express and angular for my app.

Suppose I have the following factory:

```
angular.module('LiveAPP.factory',[])
.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', dataFactory])


function dataFactory($http){
  var dataFactory = {};

  dataFactory.checkDb = function(){

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/artistsearch',
        data: "Need this data to go to the request body"
    })
  }

return dataFacory;
}
```

And on the server side I have:

**app.js**

```
 app.get('/artistsearch',dbhelpers.checkDbArtist)
```

**dbhelpers.js**

```
exports.checkDbArtist = function(req,res,next){
  var newArtist = req.body;
}
```

For some reason when checkDb is invoked my get request is not passing on `data` into my req.body in `checkDbArtist`. My request body evaluates to `{}`. Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: can you check with post

Comment: This `return $http.post('/artistsearch', {artistname:"Need this data to go to the request body"})` works fine.

Comment: while you are checking through chrome emulators get will not work due to security reasons.